# Which language should be used to create Auto-IT like scripts for screen detection?

Tags: automation, computer-vision, android-uiautomator

I require guidance about auto-IT scripts(scripts that automatically control windows screen on base of scripts written). I need to know the language in which I can create such scripts or pre-made scripts which automatically control screen by detecting opened window and deciding what to do accordingly.
I mean to say the product should detect the screen and then decide what to do.

Comment: This question will likely get a better response at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Auto-IT like, why not just use autoit it can do all of these things.

Comment: auto-It  is unable to judge the which screen is opened.Screen detection sort of thing cant be handled by auto IT

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't know that AutoIt is a programming language.

You should use the

```
ControllClick
MouseClick
WinMove
WinActivate
```

commands.

Just googlesearch: AutoIt "command" and read how they work.

Good luck